# Retrieving data from a Firebase document inside Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview that shows data related to transactions. I store the client data and the transaction data in different collections and documents in Firebase. The transaction document contains a clientId that links the client data so I can retrieve it when I retrieve the transaction data and build the listview.

I have created a function, GetClientName, to retrieve the client data and I try to call it while building the listview but since I am getting the error "Methods can't be invoked in constant expressions." where I am trying to insert the client name.

How can I do this?

Below is the code I use to do this

```
  Future<String?> GetClientName(String clientId) async {
    final DocumentSnapshot clientData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('client')
        .doc(clientId)
        .get();

    String clientName = '$clientData["fName"] $clientData["lName"]';
    return clientName;
  }

    body: SafeArea(
              child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('company')
                      .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
                      .collection('trxns')
                      .where("trxnStatus", isNotEqualTo: "Archived")
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return snapshot.hasData
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data?.size,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  isThreeLine: true,
                                  title: const Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Client: ${GetClientName(snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientId'])} <<< ISSUE IS HERE
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.blueAccent),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text.rich(
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyAddress'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                          '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyCity'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                          '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyState'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                        TextSpan(
                                          text:
                                              '\nPrice: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['contractPrice'] ?? 'n/a'}\nStatus: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['trxnStatus'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                              color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Text(
                                      'MLS#: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['mlsNumber'] ?? 'n/a'}\n${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientType']}'),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const TransactionDetailScreen(
                                                false, false),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : const Text('No Date');
                  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. I had to add a future: in the code.